# Shrink ibdata1 and ib_logfile0

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-5.7

I want to reduce the size of the **ibdata1** and **ib_logfile0** files on my MySQL server 5.7. However, I do not want to activate the `innodb_file_per_table` option.

What would be the best option to reduce the size of above mentioned files without activating `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: Curious about the reason, to not activate the innodb_file_per_table option. Would you be able to share it?

Answer (score 1):

**`ibdata1` is messy to shrink.**  For 5.7, see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-resize-system-tablespace.html for thorough details on dumping, deleting, and reloading.  That's essentially the only option.

You may as well change `innodb_log_file_size` (in `my.cnf`) before the load.

**To resize just `iblog*`** --

1. `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`
2. do graceful shutdown
3. change `innodb_log_file_size`
4. start

I recommend **`innodb_file_per_table=ON`** for 'large' tables, at least when doing `CREATE` or `ALTER`.  Then maintenance on such tables not bloat ibdata1.  (I prefer `OFF` for small tables.  Yeah, it is messy to have some tables FPT, some not.)

Note: changing FPT is *not* a way to shrink `ibdata1`; `ibdata1` *only grows*.

I recommend not letting free disk space drop below the size of the largest table.

Comment: In completing Rick's answer. Ib_logfile* is not related to innodb_file_per_table. They are for redo logs and you can change size of them.

Comment: Older versions would spit at you if you did not include a restart when changing log_file_size.